# Limiting Textfields in Java

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to limit a textfield to only allow numbers 0-100, thereby excluding letters, symbols and such as well? I have found a way, but it is way more complicated than seems necessary.

Comment: What class are you talking about specifically?  java.awt.TextField?

Comment: would be nice to know the way you found...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you must use a text field you should use a [JFormattedTextField](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) with a [NumberFormatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html). You can set the minimum and maximum values allowed on the NumberFormatter.

```
NumberFormatter nf = new NumberFormatter();
nf.setValueClass(Integer.class);
nf.setMinimum(new Integer(0));
nf.setMaximum(new Integer(100));

JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
```

However, Johannes suggestion of using a JSpinner is also appropriate if it suits your use case.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice one. Didn't know that yet. +1 as this is actually a text field instead of a text field + scroll bar :-)

Comment: `JFormattedTextField ` also works well with `InputVerifier `: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you should go with a [JSpinner](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) in this case. Text fields are pretty complicated to work with in Swing since even the most basic single-line ones have a full-blown Document class behind them.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [DocumentFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) of the PlainDocument used by the JTextField. The methods of the `DocumentFilter` will be called before the content of the `Document` is changed and can complement or ignore this changes:

```
    PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
    doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr)
        throws BadLocationException {
            if (check(fb, offset, 0, text)) {
                fb.insertString(offset, text, attr);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
        throws BadLocationException {
            if (check(fb, offset, length, text)) {
                fb.replace(offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        }
        // returns true for valid update
        private boolean check(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int i, String text) {
            // TODO this is just an example, should test if resulting string is valid
            return text.matches("[0-9]*");
        }
    });

    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.setDocument(doc);
```

in the above code you must complete the `check` method to match your requirements, eventually getting the text of the field and replacing/inserting the text to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

you must implement and add a new [DocumentListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to your textField.getDocument(). I found an implementation [here](http://jcomponents.org/xref/org/jcomponents/swing/SelfValidatingJTextField.html).