# java: is the default document of a JTextField always a PlainDocument?

Tags: java, swing, document, jtextfield

Is this always true?

```
new JTextField().getDocument() instanceof PlainDocument
```

Because I have read many examples of `PlainDocument` where they always create a new `PlainDocument` and then assign it to a `JTextField`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139524/limiting-textfields-in-java/2140197#2140197).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just checked out. The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) says yes. The empty constructor always uses `createDefaultModel()` and [`createDefaultModel()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#createDefaultModel%28%29) always returns a `PlainDocument`.

-> Yes is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a class which implements the Document interface is passed to the JTextField constructor, the `createDefaultModel()` method is called, which does create a PlainDocument.